# Access Angular sub-routes without webserver

Tags: angularjs, webserver, router

If I have an Angular app that's located at `http://example.com` and I have templates that I want to be able to access at `example.com/contact`, `example.com/demo`, etc, is there anyway to access one of those links directly in the browser (say `example.com/contact`) without the use of a web server? Or will I have to change my url structure to match `example.com#contact`.

I have a node server already but I'd prefer to use a hosting option that didn't require it.

EDIT:

To clarify, this is not about getting the routes to be pretty. I already have `html5mode` enabled so that if I were to click nav buttons for example, the url gets nicely changed without going to another page. This is about directly typing in a "sub-route" into the address bar, something like `example.com/demo` and hitting enter.

Answer (score -1):

what you want is to basically remove the # in the url. you can do that by enabling html5mode in angular.

in your app.config add below line

```
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

read more about it [here](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

Comment: No I have that already; what I'm talking about is directly accessing a sub-route, something like, `http://example.com/demo` (by typing it in the browser and hitting enter) and having it load the demo template. Even with html5mode enabled, I get back a 404

Comment: if you are getting 404 with html5mode then its an issue with the route setup that you have, you dont need anything else apart from html5mode to directly access `http://example.com/demo` , you can do that - we r doing the same in our app with html5mode setup

Comment: Which router are you using, `ui-router` or `ngRoute`?